# mmenu search to trigger website (global) search

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, mmenu

I was wondering if it's possible for the search in mmenu to trigger a website search rather than just return items within the menu?

The results don't need to display in the menu but pressing enter or clicking/tapping the search button would submit the global website search and redirect to `/search`.

Is this possible? I'm sure I've seen it somewhere but I can't find where. I imagine some jQuery would be needed to change the function of a submit button?

I'm not sure if it's important but this will be on a Shopify website and there is a search form in the header marked up like this:

```
<form action="/search" method="get" role="search" class="search"> 
    <input type="search" 
           name="q" 
           id="Search" 
           class="text-input search__input" 
           value="" 
           placeholder="Search"> 
    <button type="submit" class="search__btn"> 
        <svg class="icon icon--search"><use xlink:href="#icon-search"></use></svg>  
    </button> 
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of scenarios here

**When page reload is allowed**

This is the simplest scenario, if page reload is allowed your form will be submitted to `search?q=some search`, which should be a valid route for server you can then fetch the results based `?q=some search` and render them on your front end

**When page reload is not allowed**

This can be comparatively bit trickier and implementation will depend on the frontend framework you are working on but rough implementation will be something like

- You will bind `onFormSubmit` event to your form
- When the form submits you will prevent the form submission and read the `q` parameter
- You will change the state of your application by redirecting to `/search` page with the parameter `q`
- The component/page responsible for `/search` will initiate the request for search results

Comment: Page reload would be fine. I’d see it working as though a form was submitted and the page changes to /search!

Comment: Within mmenu there is a few options to make the search a global search rather than searching within the menu. I've managed to set that up here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xzxvaa when pressing submit the page does divert to /search but with no search results. Can you see if I'm missing anything obvious as it's ignoring the value?

Comment: it appears you are not setting a name for the input field which is not resulting in any data being posted, you can configure it just like your configured form http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/addons/searchfield.html

Comment: That did the trick, I just gave it a name of `name=q` which matches the main website search and it works great now. Thanks a lot! :)